# How to extract a string from a Linq-Collection

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, linq, lambda

I try to extract a single String from a collection. My code works so far, but i'd like to shorten the last part to one line like in my example:

```
private static void QueryText(Guid g)
{
    var collection = from produkt in Entity.Memory.mProduktCollection.mProdColl
                     let p = produkt as Entity.Base.Produkt
                     from version in p.version
                     let v = version as Entity.Base.Version
                     from customer in v.customerCollection
                     let c = customer as Entity.Base.Customer
                     from fehler in v.fehlerCollection
                     let f = fehler as Entity.Base.Fehler
                     select new { c, p, v, f };
    collection = collection.Where(x => x.f.id == g);

    List<string> lp = new List<string>();
    lp.AddRange(collection.Select(x => x.p.name));
    Entity.Anzeige.Text.produkt = lp[0];
}
```

EXAMPLE:

something like this:

```
Entity.Anzeige.Text.produkt = collection.Single(x=>x.p.name);
```

It says string can't be converted to bool (but x.p.name is a string!)

instead of:

```
List<string> lp = new List<string>();
lp.AddRange(collection.Select(x => x.p.name));
Entity.Anzeige.Text.produkt = lp[0];
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can omit the `Where` clause. Instead of

```
collection = collection.Where(x => x.f.id == g);

List<string> lp = new List<string>();
lp.AddRange(collection.Select(x => x.p.name));
Entity.Anzeige.Text.produkt = lp[0];
```

just use

```
Entity.Anzeige.Text.produkt = collection.Single(x => x.f.id == g).p.name;
```

---

```
Entity.Anzeige.Text.produkt = collection.Single(x=>x.p.name);
```

> It says string can't be converted to bool (but x.p.name is a string!)

`Single` expects a function returning a `bool`. `x=>x.p.name` returns a `string`; hence the error message.

---

A more literal translation of your code would be to use [`First`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb535050%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead of [`Single`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/bb535118%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), since `Single` will throw an exception if more than one element is found.

Comment: `Entity.Anzeige.Text.produkt = lp[0]` would be translated to `First`, not `Single`.

Comment: @ken2k I know that. But OP used single in his attempt. I edited my answer to make that clear.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for the following:

```
Entity.Anzeige.Text.produkt = collection.Single().p.name;
```

Note: your usage is a bit inconsistent - `Single()` selects the first element and throws an exception if there's more than one. If it's possible that you have 2+ items, use `First()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
Entity.Anzeige.Text.produkt = collection.First().p.Name;
```